# Blackberry app very slow why using Sqlite Queries in loop

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I am working on bb app , app is complete but its very slow while selecting data from sqlite ,I am not able to find any solution to boost up the performance, please see code below

```
for(int a=0;a<200;a++){
   retrieveCode(selectQuery);
}
```

where

```
public String retrieveCode(String query)
{
    String s = "";   
    Vector v = new Vector();

    try
    {
        g.vec_Result = new Vector();

        // Read in all records from the Category table
        Statement statement = _db.createStatement(query);//"SELECT * FROM samples"

        statement.prepare();
        Cursor cursor = statement.getCursor();              

        Row row;
        // Iterate through the result set.  For each row, create a new
        // Category object and add it to the hash table. 
        while(cursor.next())
        {
             row = cursor.getRow();

             s = row.getString(0);
             v.addElement(vmd);
        }
        statement.close();
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch(DatabaseException dbe)
    {
        g.errorDialog(dbe.toString());
    }
    catch(DataTypeException dte)
    {
        g.errorDialog(dte.toString());
    }
    s = v.firstElement().toString();
    return s;    
}
```

I am developing for OS5.0 , please help

Comment: Do you have some performance numbers to share?  Try instrumenting your loop that iterates 200 times, to see how the performance varies over time.

Comment: Is there code we are not seeing?  What Is vmd? "v.addElement(vmd);"
"